# preg_replace(): why is it truncating this string?

Tags: php, preg-replace

This should be obvious, but I'm having trouble.

I want to replace several characters (dashes, spaces, underscores) with an empty string, but I've got something wrong.

This code: `$tmp = preg_replace('/[ -_]/', '', 'filename-1055');`

...returns this: `"filename"`

...when I'm expecting this: `"filename1055"`

Why the truncation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a character class, dash `-` is the range operator, so your class `[ -_]` means any character in the range  (space) to `_`.

You have two possibilities:

1-  move the dash in the first or last position in the character class: `[- _]` or `[ _-]`
2- or escape it: `[ \-_]`

Answer (score 2):

Try [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead:

```
$tmp = str_replace(array("-", "_", " "), "", 'filename-1055');
```

Unless there is a particular reason you are using `preg_replace`.

Comment: Actually, `str_replace(array("-", "_", " "), "", $string);` would meet OPs requirements better. "I want to replace several characters (dashes, spaces, underscores) with an empty string"

Comment: You're welcome. For this scenario, `str_replace` is much less overhead for a simple task than `preg_replace`. **+1**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uZ7xK9/1)

```
$re = "/([-\\s_])/"; 
$str = "filename-1055\n"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you did not escape `-` (range operator inside `[]`) with `\-`. Correct code would be:

```
$tmp = preg_replace('/[ \-_]/', '', 'filename-1055');
```